# Create multiple query keys by URL & URLSearchParams

Tags: javascript, url

I want to create url value which have multiple key values in JavaScript.

If I do like this,

```js
    const url = new URL('http://example.com/hoge');
    url.search = new URLSearchParams(['a': ['b', 'c'], 'd': 'e']);
    console.log(url.href);
```

I achieved

```
http://example.com/hoge?a=b,c&d=e
```

But I want to have is

```
http://example.com/hoge?a=b&a=c&d=e
```

How can I get it?

Comment: are you sure using same key param used with in url multiple time `a=b&a=c` . while reading the query value is more  annoying

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
const p = new URLSearchParams();
p.append('a', 'b');
p.append('a', 'c');
p.append('d', 'e');

const url = new URL('http://example.com/hoge');
url.search = p;

console.log(url.href);
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using [query-string](https://www.npmjs.com/package/query-string)
node module

- [!] This module targets Node.js 6 or later and the latest version of Chrome, Firefox, and Safari. If you want support for older browsers, or, if your project is using create-react-app v1, use version 5: npm install query-string@5.

```
const queryString = require('query-string');

let paramJson = {
    'a' : ['b', 'c'],
    'd' : 'e'
}

const url = new URL('http://example.com/hoge');
url.search = new URLSearchParams(queryString.stringify(paramJson));
console.log(url.href);
// http://example.com/hoge?a=b&a=c&d=e
```